# VLOOKUP multiple columns for different months

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I am trying to VLOOKUP a value with multiple columns.
So I have a chart with ZIP codes, states, and an avg, min, max, std dev, etc for every month of the year.

Here is an example of one month for reference:

[image]

Next, I want to basically make a chart like so. In the AVG column I want to VLOOKUP the zip code, match it to the month and have it display the avg value (from the table above) for the correct month.

[image]

Is there any way to do this? 
Here is what I have tried thus far (the sheet with the first image is sheet 1, image 2 is sheet 2)

`VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A2:Z100,if((Sheet2!B3=2, vlookup(Sheet2!A2, Sheet1!A2:Z100,3),"")))`

I am not really sure how to change the part where it goes to column 3 so that it will change for each month.

Comment: Is month in your Sheet1 anywhere? Might want SUMIFS to match multiple conditions (Zip, Month)

Comment: @chucklukowski I apologize if it wasn't clear. I updated the question to reflect the  layout

Comment: @Chris has it in his answer. It depends on where Feb is located in how you will approach this

Comment: @chucklukowski Yeah, each month is designed in columns just like January. So if Jan is col C-F, Feb Avg, Max, Min and SD is  G-J, March is K-N, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any months in Sheet1. Are they in the table vertically (i.e. you have a 'month' column somewhere) or horizontally (i.e. you have separate avg, min, max and SD columns for each month)?

If vertical, you can use SUMIFS as @chucklukowski suggested. If they are oriented horizontally, you could use your VLOOKUP, and in the column argument, put '(MONTH - 1) * 4 + 3' where MONTH is the value from Sheet2

Comment: Each month has its own avg, min, max, and SD, I'll edit the original post to make that clearer. each column says Jan Avg, Jan Min, Jan Max, Jan SD, Feb min ETC. for all months

Comment: But in the new chart im trying to make (ie sheet 2), I have the months along the rows in numbers 1-12.

Comment: So you can use my 2nd suggestion then. Do the VLOOKUP on the entire table, but just modify the `col_index_num` argument.

Something like `VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$Z$100,(Sheet2!B2-1)*4+3),0)`

This assumes that your month metrics are all in the same order (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc, as well as always avg, min, max, SD).

Comment: You could make things easier and more flexible by changing your months in Sheet2 from numbers (1,2,3,etc) to month names (Jan, Feb, Mar) and then in the `col_index_num' argument of your VLOOKUP you would use the MATCH function to match 'Jan Average', 'Feb Average', etc within your header range (Sheet1!$A$2:$Z$100)